# Why do I get NoSuchMethodException?

Tags: java, reflection

I keep getting `NoSuchMethodException` in this line:

```
float modif = (float)sc.affectingObject.getClass().getMethod(sc.affectingMethodName, (Class<?>[])null).invoke(sc.affectingObject, (Object[])null);
```

where `sc` is an instance of class `SubChange`:

```
class SubChange implements Serializable {
    String changeType;
    Serializable affectingObject;
    String affectingFieldName;
    String affectingMethodName;

    public SubChange(String chanType, Serializable affingObj, String affingFM) {
        try{
            changeType = chanType;
            affectingObject = affingObj;
            //deciding whether affingFM provides a field name or a method name
            for (Field f : affingObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (f.getName().equals(affingFM) == true) {
                    affectingFieldName = affingFM;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (affectingFieldName == null) {
                affectingMethodName = affingFM;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //other class methods
}
```

whose instance has been initialized like this:

```
new SubChange("first", physio, "calcTotalFatigue")
```

where `physio` is an instance of inner class `Physiology` belonging to class `Hm`, while the `SubChange` constructor is being called from another inner class of the same `Hm` class.

Needless to say that method `calcTotalFatigue()` of `physio` exists.

Can anyone, please, suggest what I am doing wrong?

ANSWER

The error was caused by the wrong access modifier of the method `calcTotalFatigue()` which I naively omitted in the description of the problem. Making the method public solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is being thrown by this part:

```
sc.affectingObject.getClass().getMethod(
        sc.affectingMethodName, (Class<?>[]) null)
```

and it means that the `getMethod` call cannot find the method that you requested.

I can't determine why from looking at your code, but I suggest that you print out the classname of the class being returned by `sc.affectingObject.getClass()`, print out the value of `sc.affectingMethodName`, and double check that the actual class (or a superclass) defines the method you are looking for.

> Needless to say that method calcTotalFatigue() of physio exists.

Needless to say ... you might be wrong about that!

**UPDATE**

You asked:

> Can it be something with access level modifiers?

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) says:

> *"Returns a Method object that reflects the specified **public** member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object."*

So ... yes, that could be the problem.  If you want to retrieve non-public methods, then consider using `getDeclaredMethod` instead of `getMethod`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did what you said but that didn't help:
`sc.affectingObject.getClass().getName()` returned `Hm$Physiology`
`sc.affectingMethodName.toString` returned `calcTotalFatigue`
And inner class `Physiology` (whose object is `physio`) does define method `calcTotalFatigue`. By 'exists' I meant 'defined and name spelling is correct'.
Can it be something with access level modifiers?

Comment: @Vic don't use comments for important additions. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @Stephen C Thanks again. Method's public modifier was missing and that caused the problem.